# AWS cloudwatch cron expression scheduling issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to schedule cloudwatch event to trigger my lambda daily between 13:45 PM UTC to 15:45 PM UTC with interval of every 30 minutes.

I want my lambda to be triggered at following times daily -

13:45 PM UTC, 14:15 PM UTC, 14:45 PM UTC, 15:15 PM UTC and 15:45 PM UTC

I have set following cron expression to achieve this -

```
45/30 13-15 * * ? *
```

But I am not able to achieve the expected schedule. Getting following scheduled time instead -

[image]

Please let me know how should I achieve expected scheduled time.

Comment: The rule seems fine. Can you actually run your lambda with it and test? Could be console issue, not cron.

Comment: Lambda was triggered at the same timestamp as mentioned in the Next 10 Trigger Date(s) in the image I have provided.

Comment: I think that you will need two rules: `45 14-15 * * ? *` and `15,30 13-15 * * ? *`

Comment: Yes..I think this is the only way to achieve this...thanks!!